# How to repeat a command in cmd?

Tags: cmd

I want to know how to **repeat a command in *cmd***. So, I searched a lot and I found this:

`FOR %i in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) DO mkdir "Day %i"`

[This is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyhBF.png)

This will repeat the mkdir command and output: 10 directories, **but what if I want create about 50 directories?** How to do this? I think I will not write numbers from 1 to 50?! so what is the solution?

Comment: Before you do so, you may wish to consider naming them in chronological sort order, `01`, `02` `03`, `…`, `50`, instead of `1`, `2`, `3`, `…`, `50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **/L** parameter [(more here)](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) like this :

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,50) DO mkdir "Day %i"
// (1,1,50) => (start, step, end)
```